# Stop asking for authentication to mount USB stick

Tags: 14.04, mount, authentication, usb-drive

My Ubuntu 14.04 is asking for my password to mount or unmount an USB stick. How can I change it, so that the mount is automatic and no password input is required ?

This is about mounting arbitrary USB sticks in /media, there is no entry in /etc/fstab. My user is in the 'plugdev' group, but the password prompt is pupping up anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy
```

When it opens look for

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-unmount-others">
<defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

And change it to

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-unmount-others">
<defaults>
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Comment: Follow up question: I see that this string `<allow_active>...` shows up 29 times in that files - do you recommend to replace them all; if not; which section is the correct one to update?

Comment: Thanks. Please could someone advise if there is a way to edit this in a user-friendly manner? The XML seems to be designed to have a front-end, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, does anyone know what "attached to another seat means"? I had this problem suddenly. Could it be that ubuntu thinks my drive is in a different "seat"?

Comment: When the dialog (for password) is shown, see at "details". It should show something like: "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount". That is the rule you need to change. I had "yes" in "allow_active", so I set "yes" also in the other two (allow_any and allow_inactive). Now the dialog is not shown. BTW, I checked the [udisk documentation](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/) and found no interface for those options. I agree... there must be one.

Comment: I'm almost sure, that you could add such rule in /etc/polkit-1/...   (see this link: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=112092)

Comment: This did not work for me at all.  Perhaps if you could clarify by following up on  Jägermeister  comment and [edit] this answer it would be useful to many of us. As it is, not so much. Is a reboot required?

Comment: @ElderGeek Answer updated, hope it helps.

Comment: It did help me figure out how to solve the mount side of the problem. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Just changing `<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>`would be enough, since you are (un)mounting from the active session.

Comment: What is the point of editing files in /usr ? It will be overriden on next update.
I guess proper way of doing it is editing something in /etc. But I don't know exactly what and where

Comment: `udisks* -> UDisks*` on some distros.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good solution, to alter `.policy` files in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` directory, as other answers suggest, since the files may be overwritten on software update. A permanent solution is to create a `.pkla` file in a sub-directory of `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` directory, as `man pklocalauthority` suggests. While `.policy` files declare actions and default PolicyKit behavior for them, `.pkla` files adjust that behavior.

Start editing a new `.pkla` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-easy-mount.pkla
```

If you only care for local sessions (using local monitor and keyboard), write this:

```
[Allow local mounting without password]
Identity=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultActive=yes
```

In Debian (and Ubuntu is Debian-based), members of `plugdev` user group are [allowed to mount removable devices](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#Other_System_Groups) and members of `sudo` are allowed anything. So, you only allow password-less mounting to those who have the rights to mount anyway. (In Ubuntu 20.04 and probably in many other systems, you don't rather need to allow this, as it is already allowed in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy`).

If you wish to also allow mounting in ssh sessions, write this:

```
[Allow mounting without password]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat
ResultAny=yes
```

Here, password-less mounting is granted to admins only (`sudo` user group), because `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat` action is triggered on mounting attempt by a user who is logged in via ssh *and* is not logged in locally at the same time. So, mounting with this action potentially *allows access to a USB flash drive of another person* who is working locally. Change the `Identity` key to whatever suits your security considerations. For example, to grant password-less mounting to admins and users `john` and `mary`, you write:

```
Identity=unix-group:sudo;unix-user:john;unix-user:mary
```

Mount like this:

```
udisksctl mount --options noatime --block-device /dev/sdb1
```

Unmounting own mounts doesn't ask for password:

```
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb1
```

See `man pklocalauthority`, `man polkit` and `man udisksctl` for more details. Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today; "all of a sudden" my 14.04 wanted my password for "everything"; including (un)mount of USB sticks.

I figured that I installed openssh-server in the morning. After removing it, everything is back to normal; I can insert a USB stick; and it is mounted without asking for a password. Strange. Just tried to repro; installed openssh-server again; and no ... no such effect this time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with mounting on one of my systems. I tried using @Mitch approach above which didn't work for me (Although it may work great if you have the unmounting issue) . I took a similar approach to begin with and

`sudo gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy`

but changed this section

```
<defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

of

`<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount">`

to

```
 <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

matching content found in the old

`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks.policy`

Sources: @Mitch answer above

```
     `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks.policy`

     https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=112092
```

Testing

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem two times. Asking for password not only during mount-umnount usb but also during other task like launching any application. I solved it by restarting system. It always worked for me.